# How to search only first pattern range in sed

Tags: sed

My input file looks something like this

```
Start1
some text
that I want
modified
Pattern1
some other text
which I do not want
to modify
End1

Start1
Pattern2
End1
```

My sed pattern looks like this

```
/Start1/,/Pattern1/c\
Start1\
Modification text here\
Pattern1\
additional modifications
```

I only want the text within the first range of `Start1` and `End1` modified.
Additional, I am also specifying `Pattern1` which does not exist in the second range.

I run

```
sed -i -f <sed_file> <input_file>
```

However, my output is given below. For some reason it wipes out the second range even though `Pattern1` does not exist in it.

```
Start1
Modification text here
Pattern1
additional modifications
some other text
which I do not want
to modify
End1
```

Expected result

```
Start1
Modification text here
Pattern1
additional modifications
some other text
which I do not want
to modify
End1

Start1
Pattern2
End1
```

Comment: post the final expected result

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
sed ':A;/Start1/!b;N;/Pattern1/!bA;s/\(Start1\n\)\(.*\)\(\nPattern1\)/\1Modification text here\3\nadditional modifications/' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

In GNU sed:

- `sed -e '/START/,/END/c TEXT`

is not the same as

- `sed -e '/START/,/END/{c TEXT' -e '}'`

The first will start omitting the range from the output stream and emit one instance of `TEXT` into the output string upon reaching the end of the range. The second will replace each line in the range with `TEXT`.

Your issue is that the second range is being omitted from the output stream even though you never reach the end of the second range.  `/START/,/END/c` where `/END/` never appears is basically like `/START/,$d`

The only solutions that I can figure are clunky:

```
/Start1/,/Pattern1/{
    /Pattern1/{
        # Insert into output stream
        i\
Start1\
Modification text here\
Pattern1\
additional modifications
        # Read in the rest of the file
        :a 
        $!N
        $!ba
        # Remove the original Pattern1 line from the pattern space
        # (Remove first line and newline of pattern space)
        s/^[^\n]*\n//
        # Print pattern space and quit
        q
    }
    # Delete lines in the range other than /Pattern1/
    d
}
```